# How to make cron perform task every hour during business hours?

Tags: linux, cron

I’m trying to make a script run twice every hour during business hours on weekdays, and i have the following in my cron setup:

```
\# m     h       dom     mon     dow     command

8,48    8-17    *       *       1-5      python ~/documents/scripts/script.py
```

However, nothing is ever performed. I have tried variations on this, but nothing seems to happen at all. running the script manually works fine.

my only other cron script runs like clockwork:

```
45      5       *       *       *       python ~/documents/scripts/rdiff.py
```

This one takes a backup of my system to an external disk at 05:45 every morning.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have something in your cron log (eg /var/log/cron.log) or in syslog? Aditionnaly, Have you tried writing each hour and day of week, separated by commas instead of dash ?

Comment: there was no cron.log. in the syslog, there were a number of messages that looked like this: 
May 25 15:17:01 box CRON[5582]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
and also some that looked like this: May 25 07:54:25 box anacron[3594]: Normal exit (1 job run)
(don't know how to format this better)
i will try to format my crontab the way you suggested, and see what happens.

Comment: Does your script make use of environmental variables? [See this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work).

Comment: no environmental variables: i changed it to this: 8,48 12,13,14,15,16,17  * * 5,6,7  echo ding > ~/crontasklogg.txt
and there is no change. nothing happens. no dings in the file.

Comment: I suspect the problem is in the Python script itself, not in your crontab entry. Can you post the content of `script.py`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your crontab time spec is correct, I just verified it with this:

```
1,41 0-17 * * 1-5 /bin/echo 'running'
```

Since your 2nd crontab entry runs fine then `python` is found with your default environment (it's safer in general to use full path for executables).

Since your script itself runs fine in terminal but not when launched from cron I can only conclude that the issue lies with the difference in **environment** between your regular **interactive** session and the **non-interactive** one that cron provides.

Answers along this line (plenty of them on several SE sites) could help you investigate further: https://serverfault.com/questions/337631/crontab-execution-doesnt-have-the-same-environment-variables-as-executing-user